# Issue with qgis2threejs and compatability with QGIS 3D view

Tags: qgis2threejs

I have an issue with qgis2threejs running in QGIS 3.10.7 on Windows 10

When I open the qgis2threejs panel I get the error message below:

> "No 3D objects were rendered? There is a compatibility issue with QGIS
> 3D view. You need to close QGIS 3D view(s) and restart QGIS to use
> this preview."

I have uninstalled and re-installed both the QGIS and the qgis2threejs plugin.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open your project
2. close the 3D map view of QGIS
3. exit QGIS (not uninstall)
4. start QGIS
5. now try qgis2threejs (NOT start a 3D map view!)

If you want use both, QGIS 3D and qgis2threejs, I think, it is better to have two projects.

*I am not a programmer. I do not know, if the programmer (Minoru Akagi) of the qgis2threejs plugin could solve the problem. I think it would be helpful a communication between the programmer of qgis2threejs and the programmers of QGIS 3D (Lutraconsulting?).*
*I like it, but also QGIS 3D is not perfect. For example crashes.*

Comment: Hello,I may be missing something but I can't seem to fine where I close the 3D map view in QGIS - where can I find this to close it?

Comment: Normally you should have the small "x" within the 3D window - top right.

Comment: This is very strange as I don't have a 3D window open and it is not showing up in the list of panels open. Even if I start up a brand new project I still have the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried it with a new profile?

Answer (score 0):

I  think its related to graphic driver.I reinstalled my VGA driver and again installed Qgis and after that it worked correctly.